# How to use gettext plural definition functions in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, boolean, gettext

I have to add some external C code to my C# program, namely plural calculations from gettext PO files:
e.g.

`nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);`

or

`nplurals=3; plural=n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;`

To use these, I have to define `n`, `nplurals` and `plural`.
`n` and `nplurals` are simple ints and not an issue; however, I always get a compiler error when I define `int plural` as well as if I define it as `bool plural`.

The reason is quite obvious: C doesn't know a real bool - in C all bools are integers, and you can do both numerical and logical operations with them. The boolean handling in C# is different - you can not do logical operations like `&&` with integers, and no numerical operations with booleans.

Is there a way to use these functions nevertheless, without changing them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite simple.
Define a struct which mimicks the C boolean handling:

```
public struct CBool
{
    private int m_value;
    public static implicit operator bool(CBool cb) => cb.m_value != 0;
    public static implicit operator int(CBool cb) => cb.m_value;
    public static implicit operator CBool(int val) => new CBool(val);
    public static implicit operator CBool(bool val) => new CBool(val);
    public CBool(int val = 0) { m_value = val; }
    public CBool(bool val) { m_value = val ? 1 : 0; }
}
...
CBool plural;
```

This struct behaves like a C "bool" - you can do both numerical and logical operations with it like `plural = true` or `plural = 7`
However, as it contradicts the usual C# rules and is questionable regarding performance, it should be only used for special cases like the aforementioned. For common int/bool conversions the usual `Convert` methods should be used.